# How to run some operations in background and show a progress bar

Tags: vb.net, file-io, progress-bar

So What I got is it looks to see if the file is there then opens it i then want to save the file as the String job i would like to run it in the back ground and also not have any windows pop up and maybe show a progress bar?

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim job As String
    Dim wo As String
    Dim fpath As String

    fpath = "U:\Output\REV B Template Program Info.xlsm"
    job = InputBox("Please enter the job number.")
    wo = InputBox("Please enter the work order number.")

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(fpath) Then
        MsgBox("File found.")
        Process.Start(fpath)

        'I then wanna Save As the sting job
        'I would also like to do it in the back ground and not have it show up
        'and also show a Progress Bar if we can.
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as progress is concerned, you can't display progress that you can't measure.  Your external process is not going to report progress so you can't measure it, so you can't display it.  You might consider a ProgressBar with its Style set to Marquee in order to indicate that something is happening but not where it's up to.

If you want to know when the process has completed, you can call WaitForExit on your Process if you don't mind blocking the current thread or else handle its Exited event.

To configure how the new process runs, create a ProcessStartInfo object, configure it appropriately and then pass that to the Process.Start call.

Comment: I should add that I don't know what you mean regarding the saving part.  What exactly is it that you want to save?  Is it the output of the process?

Comment: What this is doing is opening a Excel Template and what I want it to do is, File save As, job and not have any box's pop up.

Comment: In that case, you will need to look into Excel Automation and actually use Excel COM objects directly in your code rather than spawning an external, independent process.